# jQuery UI Dialog Titlebar and Background Does Not Display in IE6

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, internet-explorer-6

The subject pretty much sums up the issue.  In IE6, we are using jQuery UI dialog to display an overlay with a form for the user to fill out; however, the background does not display (completely transparent) and the title bar does not display.

Any ideas on a CSS workaround for this?  We have the jQuery UI CSS included in the page and append IE6 specific styling when IE6 is detected.

Here is the JavaScript we are using to display the dialog:

```
$(thediv).dialog({
       title: dialogtitle,
       bgiframe: true,
       stack: true,
       resizable: true,
       height: theheight,
       width: thewidth
    });
```

Let me know if you need any other additional details!  Thanks!

*EDIT* Interesting to note, jQuery UI Dialog @ jQuery UI documentation page displays with titlebar and background correctly.  I've reviewed our CSS again and we have the correct UI theme CSS included.  Also, we load the form markup into the dialog via a jQuery ajax call.  Would this be something that IE6 craps out on?

- Jesse

Comment: Comedy Response: http://ie6update.com/

Comment: Love it, but unfortunately, our client's standard browser is IE6!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have resolved the issue. IE6 wasn't building the global CSS from our in-house combiner/cache mechanism. We directly link the jQuery style sheet in the Master Page and this resolved our issue.